# How to mount/unmount SD card that was automatically mounted at boot?

Tags: debian, mount, systemd

We have a device (actually two of them) running Debian 8.4, largely preconfigured by the vendor. There is a slot for an SD card, which (if present) is automatically mounted at boot.

Question is: after I manually unmount the card in order to fsck it, how can I mount it again? I can manually mount it again, but since it was mounted automatically at boot, it seems to me there should be a way to make the system mount it the same way again. I can simply reboot the system, but that doesn't seem an optimal solution.

Since `systemctl | grep mmc` includes this:

```
media-sd\x2dmmcblk0p1.mount          loaded active mounted   /media/sd-mmcblk0p1
```

it seems to me it was systemd that mounts the card at boot. But after `umount` that entry disappears. Systemd still is largely a mystery to me, so that knowledge doesn't help me much.

Edit: I forgot to say: there's nothing about the SD card in /etc/fstab

Edit: After boot, `systemctl status 'media-sd\x2dmmcblk0p1.mount'` says:

```
? media-sd\x2dmmcblk0p1.mount - /media/sd-mmcblk0p1
   Loaded: loaded (/proc/self/mountinfo)
   Active: active (mounted) since Fri 2016-04-15 11:47:52 UTC; 3h 2min ago
    Where: /media/sd-mmcblk0p1
     What: /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

After `umount`, it says:

```
? media-sd\x2dmmcblk0p1.mount
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

`systemctl cat 'media-sd\x2dmmcblk0p1.mount'` says nothing in both cases.

Comment: You should check `/etc/fstab` as this might be read by `systemd` and you can try to investigate what `systemd` knows about this mount point by using `systemctl`. For example `systemctl status 'media-sd\x2dmmcblk0p1.mount'` or `systemctl cat 'media-sd\x2dmmcblk0p1.mount'`. Maybe that provides some insight.

Comment: @Lucas: Thanks for your comment; I edited my answer to add the output of systemctl status and systemctl cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it.

Contrary to what I first thought, the SD card is mounted at boot by udev, not by systemd. It turns out there's a rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules` containing:

```
KERNEL!="mmcblk[0-9]p[0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="sd-%k"
# Global mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"
# Mount the device
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"
# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"
# Exit
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

So I can mount the SD card with something like:

```
sudo udevadm trigger -c add -y "mmcblk*"
```

Still a bit cryptic for something simple (I think), but it works.